# How to build a constructor for a struct within a class

Tags: c++, class, struct, constructor, initialization

I tried to build a constructor for the struct `Tri_for_one_lan` within a class called `TrigramVector`. However, it is not working, because all the `cout` I got is a bunch of memory addresses. Everything is fine before I build the constructor to initialize the struct.

Here is my .h file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct Tri_for_one_lan{
    string name;
    int freq;
    int total;
    //a constructor to initialize values of the dynamic array
    Tri_for_one_lan();
};



class TrigramVector
{
    public:
        //a constructor to initialize the values of the dynamic array
    TrigramVector();
        //to make modifications to the chracters in the files
        TrigramVector process_files(string filename);
        //store three characters of the string into the array
    void store_trigrams(int sLength, string compress_spaces);
    void expand(); //double the capacity if it runs out of spaces
        //print out the filename and trigrams in the file
    void report();
        //print out the frquency of the trigrams for each language and
        //the total number of the trigrams
    void print_freq(string language);

    private:
        //a dynamic array to store all the trigram
    Tri_for_one_lan *trigram;
    int used;
    int capacity;
        //to make all characters to lowercases
    string get_to_lower(string filename, string original);
        //to compress multiple spaces into one space
    string get_one_space(int sLength, string original, 
                             string compare_spaces);
        //check if this trigram has already existed
    bool is_appeared(string temp);
};
```

And here is my .cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "TrigramVector.h"

using namespace std;

//
// TrigramVector--a constructor that set initial default value 
//                for the TrigramVector
//    args: none
//    rets: nothing
//    does: initial the values of used, capacity, and the array
//
TrigramVector::TrigramVector(){
    used = 0;
        //There are 19683 possible trigrams
    capacity = 1000;
}

//
// Tri_for_one_lan--a constructor that set initial default value
//                  for the TrigramVector
//    args: none
//    rets: nothing
//    does: initial the values of name, frequency, and the total trigrams
//
Tri_for_one_lan::Tri_for_one_lan(){
    name = "";
    freq = 1;
    total = 0;
}
```

Comment: Format your code. This is a mess.

Comment: Where are you initializing your struct? Can you show an example of you doing that? (where the unexpected results are coming from)

Comment: `trigram` is a pointer. You need to allocate memory for it in `TrigramVector` constructor.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp what's the grammar for that?

Comment: Is `trigram` meant to hold just one `Tri_for_one_lan` or an array of them? Have you considered `std::vector<Tri_for_one_lan>`?

Comment: "It is not working because all the cout I got is a bunch of memory address." <- well this code doesn't print *anything* on the screen, so how do you know *this code* isn't working?

Comment: @immibis I only post the header file and the constructor part... I didn't post the entire code

Comment: @JohnnyMopp just hold one

Comment: @NikkyXiong Show us where the code is going wrong - that part is very important too.

Comment: @NickZ the constructor part. My program works fine without a constructor for the struct. I just initiate the trigram array within the constructor for TrigramVector

Comment: what is the purpose of `//There are 19683 possible trigrams` followed by `capacity = 1000;` ?

Comment: Your constructor is OK (although unnecessary). The problem lies elsewhere in your code. You need to post a *complete program* which *shows the problem*. Nobody else knows what your program says. [Please read this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered storing `trigram` in a [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)? A vector is a dynamic array from the standard template library.

```
//a dynamic vector to store all the trigram
std::vector<Tri_for_one_lan> trigram;
```

Comment: Yeah, after I initiate it as you said. I got a seg fault

Comment: @NikkyXiong I didn't realize it was a dynamic array at first - my mistake. Consider my edit.